# What's a word that has a meaning a 'new word for an old concept'?

Tags: word-request

*Word2* is better known today as *Word1* . *Word1* is a _____ for *Word2*

Comment: "Obi-wan Kenobi" is better known today as "Old Ben Kenobi". I used to be known as "Obi-wan" back in the day. But that was a long, long time ago...

Comment: What words have you found and rejected so far? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "retronym" might be the closest match to what you're describing. 
**Neologism** might actually be the better term.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Could you please explain more?